# Using cin AFTER getline(cin, string)

Tags: c++, cin, getline

My program should create a simple list: name(string), rating(int), watched/unwatched(string).
I understand that using `std::cin>>` leaves an `'\n'` at the end so I have to use `cin.ignore()` but it seems it also fails the other way around somehow.

```
void write()
{
    int rating;
    string name, watch, wprint;
    cout << "Modifying" << endl;
    f_list.open ("TextFile.txt", ios::app);
    cout << "Name/Title?" << endl;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    getline(cin, name);
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Rating?" << endl;
    if (!(cin >> rating));
    {
        cin.clear();
        cout << "Error again" << endl;
    }
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Watched or unwatched?" << endl;
    getline(cin, watch);
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    if (watch == "w" || watch == "yes" || watch == "y")
    {
        watch = "W";
        wprint = "Watched";
    }
    else
    {
        watch = "DW";
        wprint = "Didn't watch";
    }
    cout << name << " (" << rating << "/10) (" << wprint << ") has been added to the list" << endl;
    f_list << name << " " << rating << " " << watch << endl;
}
```

First my `cin >> rating` was always zero, no matter what I did and it also returned errors and went in an infinite loop. Then I SOMEHOW fixed it but I dont know how and now my 2 `getline()`s need to be entered TWICE!

Could somebody explain why doesn't this work for me? And which parts of this code is unnecessary?

[My input looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYmXE.png)

Comment: `std::getline` doesn't leave the `\n` in the buffer, formatted extraction does! You're clearing the input.

Comment: ... the Q&A you feared to get your question flagged as duplicate of doesn't say call `std::istream::ignore` between every extraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that using `std::cin>>` leaves an `'\n'` at the end so I have to use `cin.ignore()`

The first part is true. The second part is true only if you want to follow it up with a call to `getline`.

However, you have calls to `cin.ignore()` even before the first call to `std::cin >>`. That will expect you to enter lines, which could be empty lines but lines nontheless, the lines will be read and discarded.

Replace the lines:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
getline(cin, name);
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

with just

```
getline(cin, name);
```

Also a little bit later, you have:

```
getline(cin, watch);
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You don't need the call to `cin.ignore()` here. Remove it.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I understand it now, one question still remains for me: Why do I still get an error with my `cin >> rating`? I mean I get the number I entered but my `if` statement says that its an error.

Comment: @DownTownScarf7, you have an errant `;`  in the line`if  (!(cin >> rating));` which terminates the `if` statement. That needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `std::istream::ignore()` unless you really *know* that there is something to be ignored already in the buffer.  If you call it with an empty buffer, it will first have to fill it up -- prossibly with otherwise useful data --, and then ignore everything.