# How to read values one whitespace separated value at a time?

Tags: python, input

In C++ you can read one value at a time like this:

```cpp
//from console
cin >> x;

//from file:
ifstream fin("file name");
fin >> x;
```

I would like to emulate this behaviour in Python. It seems, however, that the ordinary ways to get input in Python read either whole lines, the whole file, or a set number of bits.

I would like a function, let's call it `one_read()`, that reads from a file until it encounters either a white-space or a newline character, then stops. Also, on subsequent calls to `one_read()` the input should begin where it left off.
Examples of how it should work:

```py
# file input.in is:
# 5 4
# 1 2 3 4 5
n = int(one_read())
k = int(one_read())
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(one_read()))
# n = 5 , k = 4 , a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: "Searching online I have only found the option to read the file line by line and split the white-spaces. I would like to know if it's possible to do this for both console and file input" Of course it is, because either way that you input, you get *a string*, and the strategy is to *split the string*. That works the same way regardless of where the string came from.

Comment: "and how to do it" You should already know how to do the splitting *from the results that you found*. You should already know how to read a file line by line *from the results that you found*. And you presumably know how to `input()` from the console. So I don't see where you have an actual *question*. You should try to write the code, read the references more closely, and only ask a *specific* question once you have a failed attempt where you are stuck on debugging and [have tried everything else](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Comment: Please also re-read [ask]. I edited your question in accordance with those standards, to remove irrelevant commentary and clearly *ask* the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try creating a class to remember where the operation left off.

The `__init__` function takes the filename, you could modify this to take a list or other iterable.

`read_one` checks if there is anything left to read, and if there is, removes and returns the item at index 0 in the list; that being everything until the first whitespace.

```py
class Reader:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.file_contents = open(filename).read().split()

    def read_one(self):
        if self.file_contents != []:
            return self.file_contents.pop(0)
```

Initalise the function as follows and adapt to your liking:

```py
reader = Reader(filepath)
reader.read_one()
```

Comment: This is broken. It does not actually let the client code know what the "read" words were, and it reads the entire file up front - which completely defeats the purpose of trying to read one word at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would just read a line at a time, then `split` this and work with each part. However if you can't do this for resource reasons, you can implement your own reader which will read one character at a time, and then `yield` a word each time it reaches a delimiter (or in this example also a newline or the end of the file).

This implemention uses a context manager to handle the file opening/reading, though this might be overkill:

```
from functools import partial

class Words():
    def __init__(self, fname, delim):
        self.delims = ['\n', delim]
        self.fname = fname
        self.fh = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.fh = open(self.fname)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.fh.close()

    def one_read(self):
        chars = []
        for char in iter(partial(self.fh.read, 1), ''):
           if char in self.delims:
               # delimiter signifies end of word 
               word = ''.join(chars)
               chars = []
               yield word
           else:
               chars.append(char)

# Assuming x.txt contains 12 34 567 8910
with Words('/tmp/x.txt', ' ') as w:
    print(next(w.one_read()))
    # 12
    print(next(w.one_read()))
    # 34 
    print(list(w.one_read()))
    # [567, 8910]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should get you close. I admit I haven't tested the code carefully. It sounds like `itertools.takewhile` should be your friend, and a generator like `yield_characters` below will be useful.

```py
from itertools import takewhile
import regex as re

# this function yields characters from a file one a at a time.
def yield_characters(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
       while f:
           line = f.readline()
           for char in line:
              yield char

# double check this. My python regex is weak.
def not_whitespace(char):
    return bool(re.match(r"\S", char))

# this should use takewhile to get iterators while something is 
def read_one(file):
    chars = yield_character(file)
    while chars:
        yield list(takewhile(not_whitespace, chars)).join()
```

The `read_one` above is a generator, so you will need to do something like call `list` on it.

Answer (score 0):

More or less anything that operates on files in Python can operate on the standard input and standard output. The `sys` standard library module defines `stdin` and `stdout` which give you access to those streams as file-like objects.

Reading a line at a time is considered idiomatic in Python because the other way is quite error-prone ([just one C++ example question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587980/using-cin-after-getlinecin-string)). But if you insist: you will have to build it yourself.

As you've found, `.read(n)` will read at most `n` text characters (technically, Unicode code points) from a stream opened in text mode. You can't tell where the end of the word is until you read the whitespace, but you can `.seek` back one spot - though not on the standard input, which isn't seekable.

You should also be aware that the built-in `input` will ignore any existing data on the standard input before prompting the user:

```
>>> sys.stdin.read(1) # blocks
foo
'f'
>>> # the `foo` is our input, the `'f'` is the result
>>> sys.stdin.read(1) # data is available; doesn't block
'o'
>>> input()
bar
'bar'
>>> # the second `o` from the first input was lost
```